# Replace newline with \n in string

Tags: bash

I retrieve the following code from a file:

```
Sizes =
217.0000;4.0000;1.0000
Uopt =
0.0000;0.7407;0.0654;0.0000
1.0000;0.6936;0.0353;0.0000
Jopt =
32.0802
Xopt =
0.0000;12.8000;0.0000;0.0000;0.0000;0.0000
1.0000;12.8034;0.2390;0.0007;0.0000;0.0000
```

I want to convert this to the following code:

```
Sizes =\n217.0000;4.0000;1.0000\nUopt =\n0.0000;0.7407;0.0654;0.0000\n1.0000;0.6936;0.0353;0.0000\nJopt =\n32.0802\n   Xopt =\n0.0000;12.8000;0.0000;0.0000;0.0000;0.0000\n1.0000;12.8034;0.2390;0.0007;0.0000;0.0000
```

I can retreive the code from the file into a string:

```
CONTENT='cat ${FILE}'
```

But how can I replace the newlines in the `CONTENT` with `\n`?

Answer (score 3):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v ORS='\\n' '1' file
```

Note that there will be a final '\n' at the end.

Comment: This is awesome. This way I can pass log file output easily in JSON format.

Comment: The backquote is a copy/paste error. The correct statement is `awk -vORS="\\\n" '1' file` Explanations: `-v` set a variable `ORS` means Output Record Separator, the single awk instruction is `'1'` which is a dummy noop, it could have been `'{print}'` instead. 3 backslashes is because bash is eating some double quote escaping before passing to awk. 4 backslashes also works. Or with only 2 with single quote: `-vORS='\n'`